# Typescript mapKey and pick

Tags: typescript, lodash, mapkeyjoincolumn

I want to convert the following js code in ts, without using loadish.js.

```
let claimNames = _.filter<string>(_.keys(decodedToken), o =>
    o.startsWith(ns)
  );      
let claims = <any>(
   _.mapKeys(_.pick(decodedToken, claimNames), (value, key) =>
      key.replace(ns, "").substring(1)
   )
);
```

or is there a place where I can find some help regarding this situation.

Comment: This _is_ the place to get help, but you first need to ask a question. We're not just gonna do your job for you.

Comment: Have a look into `Object.entries` and `Object.keys` etc.

Answer (score 0):

So you have an object, with keys starting with a ns-defined substring, let's says it is 'ns'.

Example:

```
{
  foobar: 'foobar',
  nsfoo: 'foo',
  nsbar: 'bar'
}
```

And you want to map this to

```
{
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
}
```

You can do this:

```
var ns = 'ns';
var obj = {
  foobar: 'foobar',
  nsfoo: 'foo',
  nsbar: 'bar'
};

var newObj = {};
Object.keys(obj).filter(key => key.startsWith(ns)).forEach(key => newObj[key.replace(ns, '')] = obj[key]);

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Thanks that did the job

Comment: @MuhammadKamran Would you mind to upvote and accept the answer please?